# Abstract class, repeated inheritance, specific example

Tags: python-3.x, abstract-class, multiple-inheritance, abc

I am working on a codebase that I don't entirely master (yet). I have the following 3-class stucture:

```
class Processor(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def process(self, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any):
        pass


class AbstractEsTask(Processor, ABC):
    def calculate(self, param):
         ...


@DplTask
class EsDirectTask(AbstractEsTask):
    def process(self):
        return self.calculate(param = "DIRECT")
```

**It seems to me that having `AbstractEsTask` inherit from `ABC` is superfluous, since `Processor` already does.**

I have tried editing the code accordingly (`class AbstractEsTask(Processor, ABC)` -> `class AbstractEsTask(Processor)`) and couldn't observe any change in the output. But, since it's a large codebase, this is probably not enough.
Is my understanding (in bold above) correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement is correct because when `AbstractEsTask` inherits `Processor` it will have access to all values of `ABC`.

Or in other words, if python can't find a method in `AbstractEsTask`, it will first look in Processor, and then `ABC`. Because `Processor` has all of the elements that `ABC` has, `ABC` will never be needed. If a member is not found in `Processor`, it will not be found in `ABC`.

I cannot think of any edge case where a double inheritance like you describe above would be necessary. Even if `Processor` modifies one of the methods of `ABC`, the inheritance will not be affected because `Processor` is inherited first.

This is described in the [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#multiple-inheritance)